# Webserver generates badly formatted services.wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, wsdl, cxf

I have a Tomcat 7.0 web server which I use to run a web service on it. The web service framework is CXF 2.5.2.

When testing the web service from the Eclipse Web Service Explorer everything works as supposed. However, when generating a Java Client from the WSDL (using Eclipse) and running it, I get the following error when calling `super(wsdlLocation, serviceName)` from the Service implementation:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:150)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:91)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
at test.Test_Service.<init>(Test_Service.java:43)
at test.Test_TestSOAP_Client.main(Test_TestSOAP_Client.java:47)

Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
... 4 more

Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'c' (code 99) in start tag Expected a quote at [row,col,system-id]: [1,208,"http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services?wsdl"]
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:240)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
... 6 more

Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'c' (code 99) in start tag Expected a quote at [row,col,system-id]: [1,208,"http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services?wsdl"]
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3005)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2926)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2802)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:1080)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.readDocElements(StaxUtils.java:974)
at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:901)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:231)
... 8 more
```

The interesting part should be the `Unexpected character 'c' (code 99) in start tag Expected a quote
 at [row,col,system-id]: [1,208,"http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services?wsdl"]` message. When inspecting the generated services.wsdl, I found, that the problem is in the meta part:

```
<meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

`content-type` should be normally wrapped into quotes. Is this a known bug in one of the used frameworks/servers? What can I do to work around this? And why is there no problem when using the Eclipse Web Services Explorer? Is it more fault-tolerant (as my Firefox seems to be as it also doesn't have any problems to display a graphical representation of the generated wsdl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. I accidentally specified the WSDL endpoint as `http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services` instead of `http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services/MyTestWS`. So the automatically generated client tried to fetch the WSDL from `http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services?wsdl` which returns an HTML page, instead of `http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services/MyTestWS?wsdl` which returns an actual WSDL.

Answer (score 3):

The service list page is an HTML page listing the services and providing links to the appropriate WSDL documentes for those services (or WADL docs for the rest based services).   It's not a WSDL document.   Parsing it as a WSDL would not work.

Comment: Well, the file we talk about is fetched from `http://www.example.com:8081/TestWS/services?wsdl` which should return an WSDL, shouldn't it?

Comment: Found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue/bug with the CXF service listing generation. In `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.servicelist.FormattedServiceListWriter` source (around line 52):

```
    writer.write("<meta http-equiv=content-type content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
```

i.e. the `http-equiv` value is unquoted. So there's no problem with the other tools because they're more "fault-tolerant" - as you guessed.

I'm not sure what the `com.ctc.wstx.*` classes are as it looks like this is where the validation is happening and the error is being thrown. If it's something you have control over, a (temporary) work around may be to run HTMLTidy over the service listing page?

May be worth mentioning on the CXF mail-list or raising a bug?

Comment: Just forwarded this to the CXF mailing list. Will post updates here. `com.ctc.wstx` seems to be the Woodstock XML processor. It's nothing I have control over...

Comment: Found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same exception once and it was because in a configuration file at one place I was missing doule quotes.. example `destination-name=closeTaskService`

fix was `destination-name="closeTaskService"`, error was some thing like below
`org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Unexpected character 'c' (code 99)` in start tag Expected a quote